# How can i stretch part of a geometry with a modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

is there any option to stretch just part of a geometry?
Like my image? i only need to stretch a little part of the model, i could do it on edit mode but it could be difficult since i got already a lot of polygons, is there any other way?

Thank you in regard :)

[image]

**Edit: i already tried with the edit mode, but it doesn't work properly since it doesnt fit the figure like i want.**

Comment: Another way would be to use the **Lattice Deform** modifier.

Answer (score 1):

**Already found a way to do this, i just entered in edit mode and then used the proportional editing option, and also the snap option, it worked! but i just selected the faces i wanted to stretch :)**

[image]